# Can NetScaler serve from the Cache when the Nodes are down

Tags: netscaler

We have NetScaler front of REST WebServices, We have a requirement to cache REST responses on NetScaler and serve requests from the cache to reduce the load on WebServices layer. 
Can we ask NetScaler to serve the requests and send the response from the NetScaler cache even when REST WebServices are down ?

Answer (score 0):

## Don't think so.

A [Citrix employee said "No" on the Citrix forums in 2009](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/250694-how-to-use-netscaler-integrated-cache-to-backup-web-server/). (Archived [here](https://archive.is/clKyv).) And I don't think that verdict has changed.

> Without content switching, when the vserver is in a state of DOWN it will not reply to the tcp SYN
> [...]
> The best answer here is to use the available functionality Backup Vserver and RedirectURL to forward the traffic to a separate server.